# Deployement / Transpilation of TS Cloud functions not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am working on a side project using TS and Firebase CLI 11.16.1
I usually use JS only. When I created my Firebase project I opted for Typescript for the functions. (Then saw it was TS transpiled to JS but nevermind)
I did the classic stuff : `firebase init`
Then opted for functions and Typescript instead of Javascript.

I wrote my functions without any error (in TS) in my functions/src/index.ts file.

```
exports.todayCode = functions.pubsub.schedule('every day at 00:01').onRun((context) => {
const fsdb = admin.firestore();
const colors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y", "P", "O"];
let code = "";
const date =  formatDateWithZone(new Date(),'Europe/Paris').slice(0, 10);
//generate random code from the colors array and add it to the code string

        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            code += colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
        const codeObj = {
            code: code
        }
        //save the code in the firestore database with the date formatted YYYY-MM-DD as id
        return fsdb.collection("codes").doc(date).set(codeObj);
    
});
```

I deployed using the classical `firebase deploy`
Then i did few changes deployed again. (changing the Timezone since I want it to run at Paris time adding new updates to the database etc)

```
exports.todayCode = functions.pubsub.schedule('every day at 00:01').timeZone('Europe/Paris') .onRun((context) => {
const fsdb = admin.firestore();
const colors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y", "P", "O"];
let code = "";
console.log("creating code");
const date =  formatDateWithZone(new Date(),'Europe/Paris').slice(0, 10);
console.log("today date : " ,date);
//generate random code from the colors array and add it to the code string
fsdb.collection("codes").doc(date).get().then((doc: { exists: any; })=>{
    if(doc.exists)
    {
        console.log("code existe déja !")
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            code += colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
        const codeObj = {
            code: code,
            date : new Date()
        }
        console.log("code created !");
        //save the code in the firestore database with the date formatted YYYY-MM-DD as id
        return fsdb.collection("codes").doc(date).set(codeObj);
    }
});});
```

And deployed again.
Theses changes never seemed to apply correctly. Like if the functions never updated itself.
Every time I run my functions, it's still the first version.

But the deployment logs are fine, it says functions got updated and deployed.

Then I checked the function inside cloud platform and saw a hierarchy with a lib folder.
Then checked the doc and saw it was transpiled TS code to Javascript [image]

So my code is in src/index.ts.
Cloud platform is supposed to convert it to Javascript, inside the lib folder;
Inside the lib there is an index.js, then a folder with another index.js, which are supposed to be my converted code.
First thing I don't understand, why is there two files ?

I checked, and the first index.js (lib/index.js) is still the first version of my code I wrote. (first block)
The second one (lib/functions/src/index.ts) is my most recent code. (2nd block)

When i try to deploy using CLI, everything seem to work fine. But then when I run my functions, manually or at 00:01 it's still the first version (the code of the lib/index.js)

I tried to edit manually this lib/index.js with cloud platform and deploy, it revert back to the first version.

Am I the only one who got the issue ?
My guess is : it uses the wrong functions (older) since there is one in the root of the /lib and another in lib/functions/src ...

If I can't find a way to resolve this I will try to go back to Javascript for the cloud functions and deploying again.

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is.  It will probably make more sense if you give exact details of what you did to get to the point where thing are confusing, starting from scratch, and pointing out what version of the Firebase CLI you're using for all this.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using your instructions.

Comment: Sure. I am updating the question :)

Comment: It would help if you gave the actual specific sequence of commands and oither things you did, starting from nothing.  That would help people understand what you did and how to reproduce it.  For example, you probably started with `firebase init` or something similar.

Comment: Done. Really don't have much more to say in terms of step

Comment: "*I wrote my functions without any error (in TS) in my functions/src/index.ts file. I deployed using the classical firebase deploy Then i did few changes deployed again*" - not being able to see all this work is hurting our understanding of the problem.  This is not reproducible instruction.  Please edit the question to show the [minimal complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows how to reproduce the problem.  We should be able to reproduce your result using the instructions you provide here.

Comment: updated with the whole code !

Comment: If you have an **exact** set of reproducible instructions that recreates the situation where your function does not update, you should send that to Firebase support.  Stack Overflow will not be able to help you.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

Don’t know why the wrong version of your code is being used when you run your functions. One thing you could try is to delete the `lib` directory and then run `firebase deploy` again so This will force the Firebase CLI to transpile your TypeScript code and place the output in a new lib directory, which should contain the most recent version of your code.

You can also view the logs for your functions by running the

> firebase functions:log

command to get more information about the behavior.

You may also try  to delete all the functions and recreate the function using

> firebase init

with giving typescript as your options and making sure your directories are named correctly as per the context. And deploy the function locally to verify that it is working correctly in the local environment, this can be done with [firebase emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype)

Comment: For the record, I am in touch with Firebase support, he asked me to delete the functions of my index.ts and deploy them. So it deleted them on the project, but when i wrote them back to the index.ts now it does not deploy anything !

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your answer. I deleted the lib folder and deployed, did firebase init again, and tried with firebase emulator, but now I have this error : " functions/lib/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions"

So now my new thought is that the code isn't transpiled in the right place. But I don't know why nor to fix it.

Comment: @RaphaelLopes cd into your functions folder and run this command 

`npm run-script build`

This will create the lib/index.js file that is missing

Comment: It does not work. It updates the files in lib/functions/src but not lib/index.js, so the firebase deploy does not work after that...

Comment: I have tried to replicate your issue on my end using your provided code but didn't get any error. Although I have replicated in fifebase emulators and ran `npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions` which is basically `npm serve` command from `package.json`